# Determine all the generators and subgroups of H = ⟨(123456)⟩ ⊂ S6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Determine all the generators and subgroups of $H = ⟨(123456)⟩ \subset S_6$.

I calculated all of the elements, so, I got

generator : (135)(246), (14)(25)(36), (153)(264), and (165432)
and subgroups : <(135)(246)>, <(14)(25)(36)>, <(153)(264), and <(165432)>

am I missing subgroups or generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe $\langle (135)(246)\rangle=\langle (153)(264)\rangle$, and $(165432)$ generates the whole group. Thus you've found two proper subgroups. Add the trivial subgroup and you're done with the subgroups. A cyclic group of order $6$ has $3$ proper subgroups.